# iMac software causing I phone messages to appear up on older iMac

Tags: macos, ios, continuity

Just upgraded older iMac with neatest software.  Now my spouse's text messages show up on iMac.  Her iPhone software is old and she cannot turn it off from her iPhone. Is there a way to turn it off from the iMac?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please review the [how to ask a good question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section to be sure you're not re-asking the same question as one on the site. Specifically, we can't guess what version of OS X and iOS are in play.

Comment: what is "neatest software" ? do you mean newest ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Messages" App on the iMac, go to settings and remove the iMessage account.